# How to access the ICElements of local variables(variables inside function) and variables in header file?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

Objective is to access the elements of C-file in eclipse to check customized naming rules for C-elements(global variable, local variable, function declarations).
Tried to access the C-file elements as mentioned below. In this case, only able to access global variables and function names in the .c file.
How local variables(variables inside functions) & variables in included header files can be accessed?

ITranslationUnit tu = CUIPlugin.getDefault().getWorkingCopyManager().getWorkingCopy(input);
ICElement[] ele= src.getChildren();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Local variables**

`ICElement` is mostly used for representing code elements in CDT's various *views*, such as the Outline View or Type Hierarchy. As such, local variables (which do not appear in these views) do not have an `ICElement` representation.

For code analysis use cases like this, it's probably better to use the **AST** API. The AST is a detailed representation of the entire code in a file. It can be accessed via `ITranslationUnit.getAST()`. You can then use an `ASTVisitor` to traverse the AST and visit any declarations you like and check their names.

**Variables in included header files**

There are two sub-categories here: header files inside the project directory, and header files outside the project directory.

Header files **inside the project directory** have their own `ITranslationUnit`, and you can use either the `ICElement` API or the AST API to analyze them with that `ITranslationUnit` as a starting point. Note that a file does not need to be open in an editor to obtain an `ITranslationUnit` for it. You can traverse all of the files in the project with something like `ICElementVisitor`, with the `ICProject` as a stating point.

Header files **outside the project directory** do not have an `ITranslationUnit`, and there is no straightforward way to obtain an AST for them. However, assuming your project's **indexer** is enabled, the indexer does create ASTs for them and store information from those ASTs in the project's **index**, which you could examine. There are index APIs that can be used to traverse the index; some relevant ones are `IIndexManager.getIndex(ICProject)`, `IIndex.getAllFiles()`, and `IIndexFile.findNames()`.

**Edit: Additional Tips**

1) How to differentiate between function declarations and simple declarations.

I can think of two ways:

- Syntactically, based on the structure of the AST. For function definitions, the type of the declaration node will be `IASTFunctionDefintion`. For variable declarations, it will be `IASTSimpleDeclaration`, with the *decl-specifier* being `IASTSimpleDeclSpecifier` or `IASTNamedTypeSpecifier` (you additionally want to check that the *declarator* is not an `IASTFunctionDeclarator`, to filter out function declarations that are not definitions).
- Semantically. If you find the `IASTName` for the declaration, you can call `IASTName.resolveBinding()`, and check whether the returned binding is an `IFunction` or an `IVariable`.

2) How to get the return type of a function and the variable type?

For these tasks, you need to get the binding. A variable's type can be queried by `IVariable.getType()`, and a function's return type via `IFunction.getType().getReturnType()`.

3) Is there a way to get an `ICElement` from an `IASTSimpleDeclaration`?

There isn't a simple way that I know of. However, you shouldn't need to - if you're traversing the AST, all the information you could want can be found in the AST.

Comment: 1. ASTVisitor gives the function declaration as well as variable declaration. How can differentiate these two?
2. How to get the return type of function and variable type?
3. Is there a way to get ICElement from IASTSimpleDeclaration ? Because ICElement  ia having element type and element name

Comment: Declaration 1: unsigned char variable1;
Declaration 2: const unsigned char variable2;

For declaration 1, type of the variable is returned as unsigned char
For declaration 2, type of the variable is returned as org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.dom.parser.c.CQualifierType

How do access the type as unsigned char and qualifier as const for declaration 2?

Comment: @MaruthamalaiA: `IQualifierType.isConst()` for const and `IQualifierType.getType()` for the underlying type.

Comment: How to differentiate between struct variable and enum variable in AST tree?. Intention is to get struct and enum variable seperately.

Comment: @MaruthamalaiA: After using `IASTName.resolveBinding()` on the variable's name to get an `IBinding`, cast the binding to `IVariable` and call `IVariable.getType()`. If the resulting `IType` is an instance of `ICompositeType`, it's a structure variable. If it's an instance of `IEnumeration`, it's an enum variable.

Comment: how to get the function name, start line, and length using ITranslationUnit?